# How to call this function in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

How do I call a function with return paraters in it.

```
func fordata2(data: String, completion: (jsonData: NSArray?, error: NSError?)->Void){
}
```

When I call this as:

```
fordata2()
```

I get the error "missing argument for parameter in 1# call"

What parameters do I put in it to call this function?

Comment: you r missing parameters as per your method

Comment: Read the chapter about functions in the Swift Language Guide

Answer (score 0):

You can call this method like this:

```
fordata2(data: "your string data here", completion: {
    jsonData, error in
    // your code here
})
```

To better understand it, read about methods from [Swift documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html).